# Newest firefox on travis-ci is not used by Karma

Tags: firefox, karma-runner, ubuntu-12.04, travis-ci

I am using Karma to run a Jasmine test suite on Travis-ci. I want to test in the latest version of firefox and am able to install the latest version (50.0). However, Karma is still using an old version (38.4) of firefox for the tests.

Here is my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
    - "node"
script: npm test
# sudo is needed to install the newest firefox
sudo: true
before_install:
    - firefox -v
    # install newest firefox
    - sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
    - sudo apt-get update
    - sudo apt-get install -y firefox
    # Start a display server where all graphical operations happens in memory
    - export DISPLAY=:99.0
    - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
```

The answer might be [Install Latest Version of Firefox on Travis And Run with Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602565/install-latest-version-of-firefox-on-travis-and-run-with-protractor) but I'm hoping for something without a fixed version number.

Comment: Output from travis: Setting up firefox (50.0~b5+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...

Please restart all running instances of firefox, or you will experience problems.

Setting up xul-ext-ubufox (3.2-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...

Processing triggers for libc-bin ...

ldconfig deferred processing now taking place

`firefox -v`

Mozilla Firefox 38.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of installing the latest Firefox version manually, I found that using the Ubuntu Trusty image (instead of Precise) with the 'latest' version of Firefox as `addon` works. As outlined here: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/trusty-ci-environment/#Firefox

In `.travis.yml`:

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty
addons:
  firefox: "latest"
before_install:
    # Start a display server where all graphical operations happens in memory
    - export DISPLAY=:99.0
    - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
```

The output is:

```
$ export FIREFOX_SOURCE_URL='https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&lang=en-US&os=linux64'

Installing Firefox latest

0.92s$ wget -O /tmp/firefox-latest.tar.bz2 $FIREFOX_SOURCE_URL

--2016-10-12 10:57:06--  https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&lang=en-US&os=linux64

Resolving download.mozilla.org (download.mozilla.org)... 52.200.112.178

Connecting to download.mozilla.org (download.mozilla.org)|52.200.112.178|:443... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found

Location: http://download.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/49.0.1/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-49.0.1.tar.bz2 [following]

--2016-10-12 10:57:06--  http://download.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/49.0.1/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-49.0.1.tar.bz2

Resolving download.cdn.mozilla.net (download.cdn.mozilla.net)... 65.152.202.202, 65.152.202.185, 2610:18:1440:100::d803:32d9, ...

Connecting to download.cdn.mozilla.net (download.cdn.mozilla.net)|65.152.202.202|:80... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

Length: 55201247 (53M) [application/x-tar]

Saving to: ‘/tmp/firefox-latest.tar.bz2’

100%[======================================>] 55,201,247  81.2MB/s   in 0.6s   

2016-10-12 10:57:06 (81.2 MB/s) - ‘/tmp/firefox-latest.tar.bz2’ saved [55201247/55201247]

> karma start .config/karma.conf.js --single-run

12 10 2016 10:57:42.884:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.3.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/

12 10 2016 10:57:42.887:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Firefox with unlimited concurrency

12 10 2016 10:57:42.896:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Firefox

12 10 2016 10:57:45.535:INFO [Firefox 49.0.0 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#33hXRwO5ncbWGpouAAAA with id 49996403
```